# ASP Buttons used as navigation and messes up other forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio. I have some buttons in my navigation via my
Master Template like this:

```
  <ul>
          <li><h2>Events</h2></li>
          <li><asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEvent" runat="server" Text="Add Event" class="navbutton" onclick="ButtonAddEvent_Click"  /></li>
          <li><asp:Button ID="ButtonEditEvent" runat="server" Text="Edit Event" class="navbutton" onclick="ButtonEditEvent_Click" /></li>
  </ul>
```

With the C# code:

```
 protected void ButtonAddEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("addevent.aspx");
    }
    protected void ButtonEditEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("editevent.aspx");
    }
```

On my pages with no webforms, the buttons navigate fine. However when
I am on a webform page and click a navigation button (such as Add
Event listed above) the links do not work anymore. I click the Add
Event button and nothing happens. How can I overcome this behavior on
pages with webforms?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem.

My solution was to change the `CodeBehind="WebForm.aspx.cs"` on the very top of the WebForm.aspx Source code to `CodeFile="WebForm.aspx.cs"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just checked, and it looks like my page already uses CodeFile. I wish that was it though! :)

Comment: Just let me see if I got it right, whenever you click the button it redirects to the webform but it says the webform doesn't exists?

Comment: The webform exists. When I click the button on a page (without a webform on it), it redirects to the webform page. Then if I try to click any button on this webform page, nothing happens. No webform to webform works. Webform to any other page doesn't work

Comment: Try using this:

Response.Redirect("~/WebForm.aspx")

.With the "~/" before the webform name